# Debug Inline JavaScript Code in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

My html file include:

```
<input type="button" onclick="onClick();"/>

<script>
function onClick(){
...
}
</script>
```

And I want to put the Breakpoint in the `onClick` function and debugging it in Visual Studio and not to debugging it through the browser.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

i have found that if you just open an html file by itself in visual studio you can place a breakpoint in the inline javascript but it won't get hit. i suspect that unless you see the little green launch triangle up the top (to launch with debugging), then just opening the file or viewing it in a browser means the breakpoint won't get hit.

what you can do is create a new project and select blank solution and then add existing website (even though you are creating a new  one) like it says in this post: https://www.howtosolutions.net/2022/12/visual-studio-creating-javascript-project/

then add your html file. when you launch (i chose IIS Express (Google Chrome)) you'll need to follow the prompts to enable debugging in the web.config file and enable javascript debugging.